# Convert Y/N values of razor html checkbox in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Im reading a Y/N value from my model in a razor for loop.

I want to change the value from Y/N to true/false.

```
<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => (item.ReqDowngrade == "Y" ? true : false))</td>
```

I keep geting this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.'

Is there any way I can do this without creating a server view model?

Comment: Send parsed data from controller . Either you can send true and false value

Comment: >Is there any way I can do this without creating a server view model?    it sounds like a view model is exactly what you want.

Comment: Your property needs to be `bool` to use `CheckBoxFor()` - use a view model (which should mandatory when editing data anyway)

Answer (score 1):

This declaration is totally wrong:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => (item.ReqDowngrade == "Y" ? true : false))
```

`CheckBoxFor` helper only accepts viewmodel properties with either `bool` or `Nullable<bool>` type for model binding, hence the conditional expression above should not be used. If you want to assign `Y` or `N` value to a new bool viewmodel property bound with `CheckBoxFor`, do this instead:

**Viewmodel**

```
// assumed both 'ReqDownGrade' & new bool property are in same viewmodel class 
public bool CheckReqDownGrade 
{
   get
   {
       // returns false if ReqDownGrade is 'N'
       return (ReqDownGrade == "Y");
   }
   set
   {
       CheckReqDownGrade = value;
       CheckReqDownGrade == true ? ReqDownGrade = "Y" : ReqDownGrade = "N";
   }
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CheckReqDownGrade)
```

If you still insist to not adding `bool` viewmodel property, you can use a `HiddenFor`, standard HTML `input` element with `type="checkbox"` attribute and simple JS trick:

**View**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ReqDowngrade, new { id = "ReqDownGrade" })

<input id="CheckReqDownGrade" type="checkbox" @(item.ReqDowngrade == "Y" ? "checked='checked'" : "") />
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#CheckReqDownGrade').click(function() {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

        $('#ReqDownGrade').val(isChecked ? 'Y' : 'N');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `CheckBoxFor()` does not accept a property which is `Nullable<bool>`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I created the view model.